# PHP make a loop and call another PHP page

Tags: php

I have a page **a.php** that contains a table with a lot of element. When I click on an element i go to a page **b.php** with some parameters in GET mode.

This page does something and reload a.php

```
header('Location: a.php');
```

I want to make a button that automatically call b.php for every element in the table a.php.

**My attempt** using a page c.php with a loop and file_get_contents

```
foreach(...){
     file_get_contents('b.php?id=' . $param);
}
```

this attempt failed because b.php **check if the user is logged**, checking the $_SESSION or the $_COOKIE

Comment: When you're already within PHP, you don't need to make requests to "other pages" to do something. You just `require` some file that contains code and/or call PHP functions which do what you want to do.

Comment: but if this page require a GET parameter?

Comment: Stop thinking in terms of "pages". Try this: write everything your site *does* as a function in some external file. In your "pages", you `require` the file with the functions and call the functions you need on that particular page. … It should be obvious then that you can make any page do anything as needed without "reaching out to other pages".

Answer (score 1):

You can (or should) write a function which takes a parameter.

```
function doStuff($param) {
    doSomething;
    return $someValue;
}
```

You save this as b.php and then in a.php you do the following.

```
include("b.php");
foreach(...) {
    doStuff($param);
}
```

That should do the same and would be much more elegant.

Answer (score 0):

You might be looking for 'require'. It includes the file serverside. The file-get-contents loads the urls as of you open an url, it gets parsed and only the output get returned.

```
// in file b.php:
function example(){ /* .... */}
echo 123;

// In file a.php:
// If you do this:
file_get_contents("b.php"); // You now only have "123", the output only (the echo).

// If you do this:
require_once "b.php"; // You get the echo (as that is a part of b.php), 
// But you can now also access example()!
```